# Spark Preserve Partioning

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to understand the partitioning of an RDD. What does Preserve Partitioning mean? Once an RDD has been partitioned let's say into 4 partitions and we apply a map or flatMap. These operations being transformations, they don't need any shuffling and the task related to these operations are going to run parallel on each partition. Now why does it say the partitioning is not preserved. The result of these operations would still be 4 partitions.

Answer (score 1):

> > What does Preserve Partitioning mean?

The flag

```
    preservesPartitioning
```

will mean that a child RDD inherits the partitioner from its parent RDD.

If you do not specify the `preservesPartitioning=true` then the `DefaultPartitioner` - which is a `HashPartitioner` - will be used instead - and thus a full shuffle will occur. That's likely more expensive than re-using the parent one.